# How to make CSS padding work in Chrome but not in Firefox or Safari?

Tags: html, css

I've finished my initial code in my localhost and just migrated the files to my linode. Google Chrome doesn't seem to recognize the CSS padding settings I've placed in my main settings. Firefox and Safari does not seem to have a program rendering it.

```css
main.main {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <h1>Sometext</h1>
</main>
```

Comment: Works in Chrome for me.

Comment: I am on Chrome and can see the padding. I don't know any example, where such basic stuff like padding has dfferent behavior in the most common browsers, so maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Are you using a reset.css or normalize.css stylesheet? Maybe there are default browser styles applied and this is why there are differences between browsers. If you could provide us a live link we could keep trying to solve, because in Chrome, the example is working.

Answer (score 0):

try use this

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but doesn't safari also use the -webkit prefix?

Comment: my mac at home( if you has safari you can test it

for example @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
 body{border: 5px solid red !important;}
}

Comment: I don't have a mac, so I cannot test it, just was wondering, if this is the case

Comment: i test on iphone, in safari i has border for body((((

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution: .001dpcm) {
    main.main {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
}
```